# Permesso di soggiorno renewal

Tags: visa

I have received the paper for renewal of my permesso di soggiorno from post office, on the paper the appointment date is 16 October but I want to re enter Italy in November, is this possible? Or I can't enter Italy after the date of appointment written on the paper

Comment: You can re-enter with a "visto di pernesso" releases by the Italian authorities in your country  and only if your "permesso di soggiorno" is expired from less than 60 days. I higly recommend to come back to Italy before your appointment.